# Compare two screenshots doesn't work correctly-java

Tags: java, image, compare, screenshot

i am trying to make two screenshots with 6 seconds difference, to see if there is some changes on the website.

But my code says me that the screenshots are always different, even if i test it without any changing on the screen.

what am i doing wrong?

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screensize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,screensize.width,screensize.height);

Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage image1 = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle); 
System.out.println("screenshot "+i+"");
Thread.sleep(6000);
BufferedImage image2 = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
System.out.println("screenshot "+(i+10)+"");

int x1 = image1.getWidth();
    int x2 = image2.getWidth();
    if ( x1 != x2 ) {
        System.out.println( "Widths are different: " + x1 + " != " + x2 );
        return;
    }

    int y1 = image1.getHeight();
    int y2 = image2.getHeight();
    if ( y1 != y2 ) {
        System.out.println( "Heights are different: " + y1 + " != " + y2 );
        return;
    }

    for ( int x = 0; x < x1; x++ ) {
        for ( int y = 0; y < y1; y++ ){
            int p1 = image1.getRGB( x, y );
            int p2 = image2.getRGB( x, y );
            if ( p1 != p2 ) {
                System.out.println("Pixel is different at x/y " + x + "/" + y + ": " + p1 + " != " + p2 );
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println( "Images are identical" );
```

Comment: What part does the code say is different? You have a pretty detailed message in there...

Comment: in the if (p1!= p2) block.
Pixel is different at x/y ..... 
even if there is no changes on the screen

Comment: @EmrahKarakoc What are x/y values? This should help you compare images. As said Thilo may be a clock or something else

Comment: And at what x/y coordinates is the pixel different? Just some random location, or always at the same coordinates? It could then help to look at those coordinates, whats there... (clock, mouseAnimation, glowing effect, ...)

Comment: test1: Pixel is different at x/y 438/1438: -15984846 != -15524297
test2 : Pixel is different at x/y 438/1438: -15984846 != -15524297

you are right, i think because of mouse :) but when i make a normal screenshot with keyboard,it doesnt show my mouse, but it does with java ? how i can avoid it?

Comment: but i let my mouse always at the same place?how can there be difference between two screenshots?

Comment: i know the reason now :) because of a small popup from one of my jar, which is hard to see ! thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your code and my pixel is different because of a blinking cursor in Eclipse Console.

Then I had a problem with an animated icon (process explorer in task bar)

Finally it said Image identical.

Note : Mouse isn't part of the thing :

> Creates an image containing pixels read from the screen. This image does not include the mouse cursor.